# "Show" array of PHP in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

var arrayjs = <?php $arrayphp = array(1,3,5,6,7,10); ?>

//each? for? with jQuery {
  console.log(num);
}

</script>
```

I have array in PHP. How can i get this for jQuery and showing with loop each or for?

Comment: Please search for "how to pass PHP variables to Javascript" type question on here. This is one of the most asked topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var arrayjs = <?= json_encode(array(1,3,5,6,7,10)) ?>;

for(var i=0; i<arrayjs.length; ++i) {
    console.log(arrayjs[i]);
}

</script>
```

There is no `foreach` in JavaScript. You have to do it old-school with indexes.

To pass a PHP variable to JS, use `json_encode`.

**Edit:** You can use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) if you're using jQuery.

Comment: @MarkFondy: Doesn't matter. The array is still 0-indexed. The array can contain anything.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake :) Thanks for help

Comment: javascript does have a forEach for arrays [works in a lot browsers now](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

Comment: Am I missing something?  What about javascript's `for (x in object)` function?

Comment: @XyanEwing how can i make it? Please add new answer:)

Comment: @XyanEwing: Forgot about that, but for arrays that will still iterate over the indices. For objects it'll iterate over its properties (keys). But not values.

Comment: @MarkFondy: You seem to have hot-swapped your first comment... the jQuery docs have an example for you on how to use $.each, but for something this simple I don't see the point. The syntax isn't much cleaner.

Comment: @chris: Touche. Didn't know about. Syntax is kind of funny in that it takes a callback though. It's just a regular old prototype, not a language construct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach